# Enum variable initialization results in error

Tags: c, enums

How do I initialize a Enum variable?
For eg:

```
enum RANK{First=1,Second,Third};

main()
{
    RANK r=0;
    int marks=0;
    printf("Enter the marks obtained\n");
    scanf("%d",&marks);
    if(marks>=90)
        r=First;
    else if(marks>=80)
        r=Second;
    else
        r=Third;
    printf("Rank=%d\n",r);
}
```

The above code gives error telling that enum cannot be initialised with an integer value in RANK r=0;
But I dont understand why this error is generated though enum values are of integer type.

Comment: I believe you can cast an int to an enum if you want to force it for some reason: enum RANK r = (enum RANK) 0;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

syntax for enum should be modified.

```
typedef enum {First=1,Second,Third} RANK;
RANK my_RANK = First;
```

if you dont want to use typedef use this

```
enum RANK {First=1,Second,Third};
enum RANK my_RANK = First;
```

can also use like this

```
enum { First=1,Second,Third } RANK = FIRST;
```

Comment: I don't believe the second example will compile.

Comment: @Lundin, i have modified my answer

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, it seems likely that the error comes from the incorrect usage of enum. You either have to declare an enum variable (sloppy style):

```
enum {First=1,Second,Third} rank;
...
rank = 0;
```

or better, declare a type:

```
typedef enum 
{
  First=1,
  Second=2,  
  Third=3
} rank_t;
...
rank_t r = 0;
```

As a side note, it is good practice to either initialize all enumeration constants explicitly as above, or not at all.

---

If you still get problems after fixing the above, you probably have your compiler set to give errors upon certain warnings. The initialization to 0 is fine, as far as the C language is concerned. But some good compilers have increased type safety and will give warnings whenever you implicitly cast between enum types and int. In that case, `rank_t r = (rank_t)0;` should solve it.

No idea why you'd want to give an enum a value which doesn't correspond to one of its constants though, that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum RANK{First=1,Second,Third};
```

should be

```
typedef enum {First=1,Second,Third} RANK;
```

to use the type `RANK`

Comment: Fine, But why cannot I initialise the enum variable "r" with 0.

Comment: @ReenaCyril While defining enum you have `First=1` so when you create a variable of type RANK then that will be initialized with `First` no need to do it explcitily